# Dropdown filter is not working in angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

I have created a drop down filter in AngularJs. Please see the link. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/c5Hrqfv1eA5qfQpkYR41?p=preview 
It is working fine, but I want to replace my current JSON to a new one.

```
    $scope.data={
      "language": "en",
      "0": {
        "id": "2222",
        "deck": [
          {
            "id": "2421",
            "level": "5",
            "name": "Plaza Deck 5"
          },
          {
            "id": "2433",
            "level": "6",
            "name": "Fiesta Deck 6"
          },
          {
            "id": "2442",
            "level": "7",
            "name": "Promenade Deck 7"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I want to change with the above JSON.
Please help. 
Thanks.

Comment: How do we suggest without getting your question..please add more explaination

Comment: @ pankajparkar, I have added working example in plunker. I need the same result with new JSON.

Comment: "It is working fine, but I want to replace my current JSON to a new one.
" what does it mean? why you want to create a new JSON?

Comment: JSON structure has changed. So filter is not working.

Comment: Okay now i got that.i'll look at it afterwards..because http://plnkr.co/ is down here

Comment: Its up now..@vimal I'm looking at it..:p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are switching from simpler array to complex array.

But here is your solution

**HTML**

```
 <select ng-model="filterDeck1.deckDetail1" ng-options="deck.name for deck in data1['0'].deck">
 </select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
//filter for new json structure
$scope.customDeck1 = function (data) {
    if (data.id === $scope.filterDeck1.deckDetail1.id) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
```

You can move above filter code from controller to filter, that would be more convenient way to do it.

Here is [**Working Fiddle**](http://plnkr.co/edit/1l0V8XPwlTc8bP1cKp9U?p=preview)
Hope this could help you. Thanks.